# Problema al descargar codigo desde github con eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

A la hora de descargar un proyecto desde GitHub, tras compilar desde pom.xml los archivos, me aparecen así [image: Archivo compilado]

En lugar de aparecer así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Sabéis como solventar este problema en Eclipse?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: tu proyecto estas seguro que es de tipo maven?

Comment: Sí, de hecho debo compilarlo en jar porque otro proyecto depende de él

Comment: ya intentaste a borrar tu .m2 y reimportar el proyecto para evitar errores con el plugin m2e de eclipse?